# Validating format of phone number with an extension

Tags: ruby, regex

When running my tests using the faker gem, I sometimes get a number with an extension as so:

```
"182-062-4657 x366"
```

The following is my regex:

```
/\A(?:\+?\d{1,3}\s*-?)?\(?(?:\d{3})?\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}\z/
```

This does not work.

What can I do with my original expression to accommodate extensions as seen above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow for an optional extension that begins with an 'x', you could insert the following (optional) non-capture group right before `\z`: `(?:\s+x[1-9]\d*)?`. This allows the extension to be one or more digits.